# Importing and Exporting Nested Dictionary to Excel in an Easy-to-Edit-and-Read Way

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to export a dictionary, with the format:

```
d = {'Apple':{'Weight':12,'Colour':'red'},
     'Banana':{'Weight':11,'Colour':'yellow','Bunched':1}        
    }
```

to an excel file with the format:

```
NAME    Weight  Colour  Bunched
Apple   12      red
Banana  11      yellow  1
```

where not every key in `d` has the same number of keys themselves.

I've managed to get the importing code, but I'm having trouble with the exporting code. I've got this so far:

```
   import csv
    data = Fruits
    with open('fruits.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            a = iter(row[1:])
            data[row[0]] = dict(zip(a, a))
    data = Vegetables
    with open('veg.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            a = iter(row[1:])
            data[row[0]] = dict(zip(a, a))
```

but it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: You have written no code for writing to the excel file. You should be using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pandas [`from_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to do this quite easily:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Apple':{'Weight':12,'Colour':'red'},
     'Banana':{'Weight':11,'Colour':'yellow','Bunched':1}
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index') # convert dict to dataframe

df.to_csv('fruits.csv') # write dataframe to file
```

Comment: In the meantime there is a function df.to_excel which is even nicer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `csv.DictWriter` and `csv.DictReader` like this:

```
import csv

d = {'Apple':{'Weight': 12,
              'Colour': 'red'},
     'Banana':{'Weight': 11,
               'Colour': 'yellow',
               'Bunched': 1}}

fieldnames = ["name", "Weight", "Colour", "Bunched"]

with open("fruits.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for fruit, fruit_info in d.items():
        row = fruit_info
        row.update({"name": fruit})
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('fruits.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    ret_d = {}
    for row in reader:
        fruit = {}
        for key, value in row.items():
            if not key == "name" and value:
                fruit[key] = value
        ret_d[row["name"]] = fruit
    print(ret_d)
```

With this solution, you need to flatten the dictionary, because `csv.DictWriter` writes each row with a dict of the following pattern:

```
{column1: data, column2: data, column3: data, ...}
```

And you have to give the fieldnames, because a dict is unordered.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictReader) for more information.